# nested accordion does not seem adhere to `multiple=FALSE` parameter

Tags: r, shiny, accordion, bslib

When using `bslib::accordion()` and `bslib::accordion_panel()`, as below, I have an accordion with s (say `s=3`) panels. I want each of the accordion_panels to contain an accordion, which itself contains t (say `t=2`) panels.  No problem constructing this, as below:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

accordion(
  accordion_panel(
    title = "panel_1",
    accordion(
      accordion_panel(title = "panel_1_sub_1", HTML("panel 1, subpanel 1 content")),
      accordion_panel(title = "panel_1_sub_2", HTML("panel 1, subpanel 2 content")),
      open=FALSE,
      multiple=FALSE # this is not working

    )
  ),
  accordion_panel(
    title = "panel_2",
    accordion(
      accordion_panel(title = "panel_2_sub_1", HTML("panel 2, subpanel 1 content")),
      accordion_panel(title = "panel_2_sub_2", HTML("panel 2, subpanel 2 content")),
      open=FALSE, 
      multiple=FALSE # this is not working
    )
  ),
  accordion_panel(
    title = "panel_3",
    accordion(
      accordion_panel(title = "panel_3_sub_1", HTML("panel 3, subpanel 1 content")),
      accordion_panel(title = "panel_3_sub_2", HTML("panel 3, subpanel 2 content")),
      open=FALSE, 
      multiple=FALSE # this is not working
    )
  ),
  open=FALSE, 
  multiple=FALSE # this is working fine
)
```

Upon initiation, all three panels and each of the nested accordions are closed. As requested on the outer/parent accordion, only one accordion panel is allowed to be open `multiple=FALSE`, and this works well.

However, although each of the inner accordions also have `multiple=FALSE`, multiple panels within these inner accordions do open (i.e. the panels in the inner accordion do not automatically close when another panel within that inner accordion is selected).

Anyone know a work-around for this, or is there something I am doing incorrectly in the above design of a nested accordion?

Comment: I can replicate this. The accordion somehow confuses the nested panels. Setting an inner accordion to `multiple=TRUE`  causes strange behaviour. Try clicking on a closed inner panel to open it and you close the outer panel.

Comment: I'd suggest to [file an issue](https://github.com/rstudio/bslib/issues).